# Matplotlib: Broken_barh plots with same height

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with broken_barh plots. Is there any way to get a fixed height of a single broken_barh? The image should get bigger vertically, but proportions should stay the same.

Here is a simple example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mlp

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

broken_barh(self, xranges, yrange, **kwargs)
ax.broken_barh([(110, 30), (150, 10)], (0, 10), facecolors='blue')
ax.broken_barh([(10, 50), (100, 20), (130, 10)] , (10, 10),
               facecolors=('red', 'yellow', 'green'))
ax.broken_barh([(50, 30), (85, 10)], (20, 10), facecolors='black')

ax.set_xlim(0,200)
ax.set_xlabel('seconds since start')
ax.set_yticks([0,10,20])
ax.set_yticklabels(['Bill', 'Jim', 'Jeff'])
ax.grid(True)

plt.savefig('broken_barh_example.png', bbox_inches='tight') 
plt.show()
```

If I generate two plots, one with two broken_barh and the other with three, it looks like this:

with 2 broken_barh
http://imageshack.us/a/img195/747/brokenbarhexample2.png

with 3 broken_barh
http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/5650/brokenbarhexamplenoyran.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render fits everything into the available space.  If you want the size of the figure to grow as you add more rows, you can do it by hand via

```
 fig.set_size_inches(w, h * num_rows, forward=True)
```

to force a fixed bar height.

[(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches)